# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined . node.js how to export oracle db connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express, node-modules

Hi I am new to node and oracle.I have created a app and made a successfull connection to db.
I need to use connection object across the application how can i do that?

Below is my index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api",authRoute) ;

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Node Server : Running on port 3000...");
})
```

database connection file => connect.js

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const connection = oracledb.getConnection(
    {
      user          : process.env.USER,
      password      : process.env.PASS,
      connectString : process.env.ConnectString
    },
    function(err, connection)
    {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');
    connection.close(function(err){
        if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
        }
    });
});
module.exports = connection;
```

I want to use this db connection in my auth.js file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../database/connect');


router.post("/authenticate",function(req,res){

    //console.log(req);
    const user = req.body.username;
    const username = {"name" : user};
    const pass = req.body.key;
    const password  = {"pass" : pass};
    //const result = db.execute('select * from usertable');// this doesn't work
    //console.log(result.rows);
    res.send('success');
});

module.exports = router;
```

when i run `const result = db.execute('select * from usertable');` I get the error below.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
```

**What am i doing wrong.Can anyone please help.Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem. You must install Oracle install client v 19 in your machine. You have to go to web [install oracle instant client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.html#GUID-A0AAF57E-D74F-43F1-BD92-81D197EFE17F) base on your machine.

Comment: Actually the version of Oracle Instant Client isn't relevant to the question.  The underlaying node-oracledb driver works with many versions of the Oracle client libraries, giving it interoperability to connect to various different DB versions.  There is no mention of a version problem or database error from having a wrong version in the question.  Also, the link given is for installation for a specific (and old) use.  It's better to follow the installation instructions on the relevant Instant Client download page. https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

Comment: if you never install it, just insall. Oracledb package need Oracle instant client, if you not install it, function oracledb package will not work.

Comment: Absolutely.  But it doesn't have to be 19c.

Answer (score -1):

(Update: there is a multi-part series with code showing what you want at https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/main/javascript/rest-api)

Use a connection pool that is opened at app start.  Then the pool cache can be used to get the pool (and then connections) in other modules.

For a web app like yours you definitely want to use a connection pool for performance.

There's a big section on connection pooling in the [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpooling).  E.g see [Connection Pool Cache](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolcache) which says:

> When pools are created, they can be given a named alias. The alias can
> later be used to retrieve the related pool object for use. This
> facilitates sharing pools across modules and simplifies getting
> connections.

The [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) are worth reviewing.

Comment: I have gone through the examples..but couldn't workout .From what i understand is my connection is being exported before being generated. How can i use callback in case of my code?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/webappawait.js and https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: @SwapnilShende would appreciate if you could share the solution I'm facing the same issue